# Create War file using Buildr

Tags: buildr

I am very much new to buildr. I am trying to create war file using buildr as i installed Jruby and buildr on my system but i am not able to build the war file.

buildfile content:

```
    repositories.remote << "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2"

        define "Sample", :version=>"1.0.0" do

           package :war

       end
```

I run the command

> buildr build

from cmd it showing the result like

> building Sample completed in xx seconds

but i am not able to see any war file

Kindly help me I am not sure where i am missing or doing any wrong step

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `build` command doesn't package the .war file.

Try `buildr package`.

Comment: Thanks alex for the response i tried same command but no luck 
got below response "D:\Technical\JSF>buildr package
(in D:/Technical/JSF, development)
No projects defined for directory D:/Technical/JSF
No projects defined for directory D:/Technical/JSF
Running integration tests...
No projects defined for directory D:/Technical/JSF
Completed in 0.110s"

Comment: in buildfile i have mentioned wrong project name.. corrected now its building thanks for this..